# Python 3 - Base64 Encoding

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, base64

I have some images, that I need to give to a server using JSON. I decided to use Base64 as encoding system. 
In Python 2, I could simply use:

```
with open(path, "rb") as imageFile:
    img_file = imageFile.read()
    img_string = base64.b64encode(img_file)
```

but in Python 3 it doesnt work anymore. 
What do I have to change to get this in Python 3 to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a code running on Python 3.7:

```
# Get the image
image = open(path, 'rb')
image_read = image_read()

# Get the Byte-Version of the image
image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)

# Convert it to a readable utf-8 code (a String)
image_encoded = image_64_encode.decode('utf-8')

return image_encoded
```

Comment: second line it has to be `image.read()`

Answer (score 2):

I followed the solution from this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/base64-encoding-and-decoding-using-python--cms-25588) it seems to work for me. So when you read the image in binary convert it to a string and then just encode the string with base64. The following solution is from the link above. Here is the tested [code](https://repl.it/@realmagicalunicorn/OrangeredScaredFunnel).

```
import base64
image = open(image, 'rb') 
image_read = image.read() 
image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
```

Comment: Tried it a couple times, but it doesnt work for 3.7. `base64.encodestring(s)` is deprecated since Python 3.1.

Comment: base64.standard_b64encode(content) is another way of doing the same thing. I encoded the image using this method check the code. Please check the link. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html#base64.standard_b64encode